# java phone format change using String builder and split

Tags: java, arrays, string, builder

Im trying to reformat the string phone number to `+1(204)867-5309` by first of all splitting the dots in the middle then checking if its the input is valid and if not a `throw new IllegalArgumentException`. But for some reason the output of the number doesnt change even though I used the String builder to change it. 
thanks in advance.

```
public class format{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        String phone = "204.867.5309"; 
        System.out.println(format(phone));
    }

    public static String format(String phone){
        char [] phoneLine = phone.toCharArray(); 
        String [] split = phone.split("\\."); 

        for (char c: phoneLine){
            if (phoneLine[3]=='.'
            && phoneLine[7]=='.'
            && phoneLine.length == 12 
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[1])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[0])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[2])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[4])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[5])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[6])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[8])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[9]))
            {  
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(phone); 
                sb.append("+1");
                sb.insert(2,"("); 
                sb.insert(6, ")");
                sb.insert(10,"-");
            }
            else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("not valid"); 
            }
        }
        return phone; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You are returning the original input (`phone`). You must be returning `sb.toString()`;

Comment: i have to write a static method named format() that accepts the string input as a parameter and returns the
formatted phone number.

Comment: I understood that. You have to replace `return phone;` with `return sb.toString();`

Comment: yes, it worked. but the dots are still in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below code.output:20(48)67-5309+1

```
public class PhoneNumberFormat {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String phone = "204.867.5309";
    System.out.println(format(phone));
}

public static String format(String phone) {
    String[] split = phone.split(".");
    split = phone.split("\\.");
    String newPhone = "";
    for (String s : split) {
        newPhone = newPhone + s;

    }
    char[] phoneLine = newPhone.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : phoneLine) {
        if (phoneLine.length == 10
                && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[1])
                && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[0])
                && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[2])
                && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[4])
                && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[5])
                && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[6])
                && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[8])
                && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[9])) {
            sb = new StringBuilder(newPhone);
            sb.append("+1");
            sb.insert(2, "(");
            sb.insert(6, ")");
            sb.insert(10, "-");
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not valid");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}}
```

Comment: I'd love to use replace but I have to use the split method.

Comment: Can you check updated code.but you need to format correctly

Comment: Yes, it worked. Just need to change where to insert the String builder. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. for loop and string splitting is not necessary:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String phone = "204.867.5309";
    System.out.println(format(phone));
}

public static String format(String phone) {
    char[] phoneLine = phone.toCharArray();
    if (phoneLine[3] == '.'
            && phoneLine[7] == '.'
            && phoneLine.length == 12
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[1])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[0])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[2])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[4])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[5])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[6])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[8])
            && Character.isDigit(phoneLine[9])) {
        String[] splittedPhone = phone.split("\\.");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("+1");
        int i = 0;
        for (String sub : splittedPhone) {
            if (i == 0) {
                sb = sb.append("(");
                sb = sb.append(sub);
                sb = sb.append(")");
            } else if (i == 1) {
                sb = sb.append(sub);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                sb = sb.append("-");
                sb = sb.append(sub);
            }
            i++;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not valid");
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to use an enhanced for loop to iterate through the characters and use use the split()method to remove the dots.

Comment: @Anj26Pro Edited the answer. Can you check now?

Comment: thank  you so much for your help, however I strictly have to use the StringBuilder to change the format.

Comment: Thank you SO much! I just have a question and correct me if i am reading it wrong, int i counts the string then when it hits the index it will append.

Comment: @Anj26Pro I didn't get it?

Comment: No, you did i just wanted to understand what is doing.